# Woocommerce - exclude products with no 'gallery images' uploaded

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a marketplace site (wc vendors + woocommerce), and we want to exclude products that do not have any additional 'product gallery' images uploaded.

This works for woocommerce_product_query:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_products_without_galleryimages' );
function hide_products_without_galleryimages( $query ) {
       $query->set( 'meta_query', array( array(
         'key' => '_product_image_gallery',
         'value' => '0',
         'compare' => '>'
     ))
   );
}
```

But I have shortcodes elsewhere that use general WP post queries specifying the product post type.  I tried pre_get_posts for that, to no avail.  What can I do with this?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_products_without_galleryimages' );
function exclude_products_without_galleryimages( $q ) {
    if (  $q->get('post_type') == 'product' )  {
       $q->set( 'meta_key', '_product_image_gallery' );
    }
}
```

Thanks!